# httpd 2.4.10 in CentOS 7

Tags: security, software-installation, yum, proxy, apache-httpd

How can I update my httpd version 2.4.6 to 2.4.10? If I try to update it with yum, it says that I have the latest version. I want to update httpd to 2.4.10 version because a security issue of the mod_proxy module (I need to use that module). If I configure the apache using that module, the network traffic uses all my bandwidth. As soon as I comment out the concerned lines and restart the httpd service, the network traffic goes back to normal bandwidth traffic.

These are the lines that I commented out, and then everything work well:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so

ProxyRequests On

ProxyPass / http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/
ProxyPassReverse / http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/
```

(The ip address was xxx'ed in order to not showing it)

May be of interest, my server version:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built: Jan 12 2015 13:22:31
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:23
Server loaded: APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Compiled using: APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Architecture: 64-bit
Server MPM: prefork
threaded: no
forked: yes (variable process count)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: The security fix was probably backported to that version of `httpd`. If you know the CVE number you can verify by look up in [the Red Hat CVE database](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/) to see what version Red Hat fixed the issue in.

Comment: I just [searched](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search-results?query=mod_proxy&search_type=all&cves=on) through all known CVE's and the latest CVE I was able to find related to `mod_proxy` was back in July of last year. [Here](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2014-0117) is the RH bulletin for it. Says it was resolved in `httpd-2.4.6-18`.

Comment: It also might help if you show us what lines you're commenting out. It's possible the CVE is unrelated to your actual issue.

Comment: Thanks! These are the lines that I commented out, and then everything work well:

`LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so

RewriteEngine on`

(Continues on next comment)

Comment: (Continued)

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somesite.gov.ar$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.somesite.gov.ar$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somesite.gob.ar$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.somesite.gob.ar$1 [R=301,L]

ProxyRequests On

ProxyPass / http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/
ProxyPassReverse / http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/
`
(The ip address was xxx'ed in order to not showing it)

Comment: May be of interest, my server version:
`Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Jan 12 2015 13:22:31
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:23
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Compiled using: APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)`

Comment: Can you add that to the original question so it's easier to read?

Comment: Done @Bratchley, should I delete the earlier (and this) comments?
Thank you!

Comment: Deleting your other comments will probably make it easier for other people to read. It may be an issue with the upstream server. From the command line can you try to do `nc -vz <hostname> 80` (where `<hostname>` is the hostname you redacted above. That will test that the server is able to connect at a TCP level on port 80 which is all that should be required for what you have above to work. I don't think it's someone DDoS'ing you otherwise it probably wouldn't immediately be seen after you un-comment those lines.

Comment: Another thing to try is to narrow it down to either the `mod_rewrite` stuff or the `mod_proxy` stuff by commenting out the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` lines and seeing if the issue still happens.

Comment: Solved! I did `yum --enablerepo=cr update httpd` and just then it let me update the httpd server from 2.4.6 19 to 2.4.6 31. Now I have the configuration without comments and everything is working fine.
Thanks to all of you!!!

Comment: False positive... :(
After trying and retrying it seems that the external network card got frozen, and that was the reason why the traffic on that card was not big.
I did a reboot and then everything come back as before.
I did narrow down the problem, the problem appears with `mod_rewrite` and the code that uses that module (`ProxyRequests On, ProxyPass`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! From [askapache](http://www.askapache.com/hosting/reverse-proxy-apache.html): "Do Not set "ProxyRequests On". Setting ProxyRequests On turns yourserver into an Open Proxy. There are 'bots scanning the Web for openproxies. When they find you, they'll start using you to route aroundblocks and filters to access questionable or illegal material. Atworst, they might be able to route email spam through your proxy. Yourlegitimate traffic will be swamped, and you'll find your servergetting blocked by things like family filters."

So, the only line to be changed is `ProxyRequests On`, it should be `ProxyRequests Off`.

Greetings and thank you for the help!